# Unable to set Apache httpd.config for static content on Jboss App Server

Tags: static, jboss, apache

I have put  alias with and without trailing slashes.Still no solution. Do we need to change Any attributes in jboss xml's also?Proxy is setting fine though.

```
Alias /images/ "c:/images/"
<Directory "c:/images">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


<VirtualHost *>
ServerName localhost
<IfModule proxy_module>
<Proxy *>
Order allow,deny
Allow from *
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /HelloWeb http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb
ProxyPassReverse /HelloWeb http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb
<Location /HelloWeb>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found the answer long back but forgot to answer it . (in case someone needs it)

I used proxypass  instead of alias.

```
ProxyPass /HelloWeb/css http://localhost/Hello/css
ProxyPassReverse /HelloWeb/js http://localhost/Hello/css
<Location /HelloWeb/css>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
```